# iOS - UILocalNotification does not fire (when set in background)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uilocalnotification

I have this code to schedule a `UILocalNotification`:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.userInfo = @{PLANNED_EVENT_ID : @"some id"};
localNotification.fireDate = someStartDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Some text";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

This method works as expected when I set the above when application is in foreground, but if I use  this code when application is in background (pressed home button), then it is not fired at all?

Why on earth will this not work? How can I get the result I need? I need to able to use this code when application is in background.

Thanks!

To be more clear, in my `AppDelegate` i have the method

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)`

When I get the first notification inside this method (which works, it is scheduled in a view controller), I schedule another notification in the same way (1 min from now). So I tried to have the application in foreground, then it worked, but when I had it in background, it didn't.

Tested on Simulator though.

Comment: How is it running in the background? Is it really running?

Comment: @Wain, do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)
```

is called when the app opens after a local notification has been shown to the user **and** the user has opened the app from the notification. If the user doesn't open the app from the notification then this method will not be called. So your next notification is never actually added.

Comment: Alright I see, just to understand. Why do we check the application state in this method if it does not get called only when user clicks on it? But it is called if application is in foreground.

Comment: Check what? It could be called while the app is in use already or if the app has just come back from inactive / dead.

Comment: I have seen examples with "applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground" then do presentLocalNotificatioNow. else if "applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive" then show an alert view.

Comment: The `UIApplicationStateActive` makes sense as the OS does not present for you if the app is active. The other check doesn't make sense as the notification has already been presented.

Comment: Okey, just wanted to check. So there actually no way to know when a notification came in?

Comment: Not unless the app is already active or the user activated it (but that could be any amount of time later from the notification in notification centre).

Comment: my last question mate, sorry to be asking so much. Can I always show an alert view in didReceive delegate? So the user can see it even when app is in background, or will it crash when app has been terminated?

Comment: You could always show an alert. I'd say it's a bit weird as the user may have already seen a notification. It shouldn't cause a crash (the alert wouldn't be shown with the app in the background).